# Validation and inheritence

Tags: inheritance, aurelia

I have created the following base class called baseModel.js

```
import { Validation } from 'aurelia-validation';

let id;
let version;
let validation;

@inject(Validation)

export class BaseModel {

constructor(validation) {

    this.validation = validation;

    }
}
```

I am extending it in the supplierModel.js

```
import { BaseModel } from "./baseModel";

let apSupplierCode;
let discountRate;

export class Supplier extends BaseModel {

constructor() {
    super();

    super.validation = validation.on(this)
        .ensure('apSupplierCode')
            .isNotEmpty()
            .hasLengthBetween(3, 6)
        .ensure('discountRate')
            .isNotEmpty()
            .containsOnlyDigits()
            .isBetween(10, 45.99);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error in the console

```
inner error: ReferenceError: validation is not defined
    at new Supplier  http://localhost:9000/dist/models/supplierModel.js:63:55)
```

I have tried with a get / set accessors, super.validation and just validation but it makes no difference.

Why can't Supplier see a variable in it's parent (BaseModel) class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the dependency injection works like that, it will only inject on the current object you are creating. This may defeat the purpose but what you'll need to do is something like:

```
import { Validation } from 'aurelia-validation';
export class Supplier extends BaseModel {

@inject(Validation)
constructor(validation) {
    super(validation);
    // Do stuff
    }
}
```

The other alternative is explicitly load the dependency from the container in the base class

```
import {Container} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {Validation} from 'aurelia-validation';

export class BaseModel {   
constructor() {        
    this.validation = Container.instance.get(Validation);    
    }
}
```